# Active record check if rich text is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actiontext

I have user model which has description as rich text

```
has_rich_text :description
```

I want to run a query to check which users have a description present?

Something like this

```
User.where.not(description: nil)
```

My question:

- is it possible to check action text presence?
- can create a migration on User model has_description(boolean) and update on `before_save` & then run query `where has_description true`

Answer (score 0):

Rails automatically adds a `has_one` association [`rich_text_#{name}`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.1/actiontext/lib/action_text/attribute.rb#L53-L55):

You can use it to join (or preload) the association and filter out the internal Action Text table:

```rb
User.joins(:rich_text_description) 
    .where("action_text_rich_texts.body IS NOT NULL")
```